# Missing config.ini after build EOS

Tags: nodeos, build

I built EOS successfully. Then the following document [here](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/docs/configuration-file) says **config.ini** file location for linux is`~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config` . But I **don't have eosio** **folder** **under the `~/.local/share`**.

So if I create eosio/nodeos/config folder and config.ini file manually then execute `nodeos --config-dir ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini` am I doing wrong ? If yes, where is my default config.ini file ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So i found the location of config.ini file. Here is location: **`/root/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini`**

Answer (score 0):

They added this recently.  Nodeos no longer generates a blank config.ini by default:

```
nodeos --print-default-config                Print default configuration template
```

Comment: It's print inside the file(config.ini) but i need the file location. Cuz I don't want to configure in command line. And I also want to know is there any wrong something or problem

Answer (score 0):

1. run nodeos first
2. then you can find on `config.ini` file

   `[root@iz2zegkkxys4vbpudfrjvzz src]# nodeos -d /data/eos --config-dir /etc/eosio/nodeos/config`

> info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.046 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:333
>   plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin warn 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.046 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:605
>   plugin_initialize    ] Starting up fresh blockchain with default
>   genesis state. info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.076 thread-0 
>   http_plugin.cpp:422           plugin_initialize    ] configured http
>   to listen on 127.0.0.1:8888 info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.076 thread-0 
>   net_plugin.cpp:2901           plugin_initialize    ] Initialize net
>   plugin info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.076 thread-0  net_plugin.cpp:2927
>   plugin_initialize    ] host: 0.0.0.0 port: 9876 info 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0  net_plugin.cpp:2998
>   plugin_initialize    ] my node_id is
>   710a9cb539f5f822a0efc2abb08c5a3ce9651ae6c5267aea7b5bb0bfbe53b3e3 info 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0  main.cpp:110                  main
>   ] nodeos version v1.4.4 info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0 
>   main.cpp:111                  main                 ] eosio root is
>   /root/.local/share info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0 
>   main.cpp:112                  main                 ] nodeos using
>   configuration file /etc/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini info 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0  main.cpp:113                  main
>   ] nodeos data directory is /data/eos error 2018-12-19T06:54:33.077
>   thread-0  controller.cpp:1596           startup              ] No head
>   block in fork db, perhaps we need to replay warn 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.077 thread-0  controller.cpp:574
>   initialize_fork_db   ]  Initializing new blockchain with genesis state
>   info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.116 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:707
>   plugin_startup       ] starting chain in read/write mode info 
>   2018-12-19T06:54:33.116 thread-0  chain_plugin.cpp:711
>   plugin_startup       ] Blockchain started; head block is #1, genesis
>   timestamp is 2018-06-01T12:00:00.000 info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.116
>   thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:486           plugin_startup       ] start
>   listening for http requests info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.116 thread-0 
>   net_plugin.cpp:3017           plugin_startup       ] starting
>   listener, max clients is 25 info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.116 thread-0 
>   producer_plugin.cpp:714       plugin_startup       ] producer plugin: 
>   plugin_startup() begin info  2018-12-19T06:54:33.116 thread-0 
>   producer_plugin.cpp:748       plugin_startup       ] producer plugin: 
>   plugin_startup() end

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for console output. Just copy paste the text and use markdown to highlight it.